# Why does it fail every time it wants to create the super user account in CA SiteMinder during Policy Server Installation?

Tags: single-sign-on, siteminder, policy-server

I'm trying to install the **CA Policy Server** from **CA Single Sign-On** (formerly CA SiteMinder)but after three or four times I'm getting always same error

```
COMMAND: "C:\Users\Administrator.AJC\AppData\Local\Temp\2\195853.tmp\smreg"      -su ******
RETURN: -1
STDOUT: The policy store could not be initialized.
Failed to create the super user account.
STDERR:
***
```

I tried to do what is mentioned on discussion "[The policy store could not be initializated](https://communities.ca.com/message/241728388#241728388)" from CA Security Single Sign On Community:

```
BASE TABLES: C:\F6\CA\siteminder\db\SQL\sm_mssql_ps.sql
XPS TABLES: C:\F6\CA\siteminder\xps\db\SQLServer.sql
Siteminder XDD files:  XPSImport C:\F6\CA\siteminder\xps\dd\SmMaster.xdd
```

But cannot run XPSImport. Also I cannot run `smreg -su password` and I don't have any idea what I'm doing wrong. I also googled about it but didn't found any solution. Any information you need to know in order to help me, just say it. I'm a little bit newbie with this lkind of environment (MS Windows Server, MS SQL Server, etc.)

King regards.

PS: I'm trying to do this in Windows Server 2012 R2 and I have installed SQL Server 2012. I decided to create the Policy Store in SQL Server. SiteMinder version is 15.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CA SSO hasn't release any CA SSO version for MS Windows Server 2012 yet(they confirmed it to me in the official [CA Communities Forum](https://communities.ca.com/thread/241735706?sr=stream). See: *Richard.Leto Jul 22, 2015 6:41 PM* answer). So the installation is prone to fail. After installing CA SSO in MS Windows Server 2008 R2 and follow all the indications of this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOd35Iyc_h0) everything went ok.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I have installed 12.52 sp2 on sql server 2012 and it worked fine. It gave the same error but on further analysis I found the System DSN was not working.

1. Go to Setup ODBC data sources (32 bit) in windows/10 and check
   System DSN with the name "CA SiteMinder DSN".
2. Click Configure and test connection if it is failing mostly due to SQL Server Browser service being disabled.
3. Open Command Prompt and type services.msc and change SQL Server Browser service from disabled to Manual and start.
4. Now run the command "C:\Users\Administrator.AJC\AppData\Local\Temp\2\195853.tmp\smreg" -su ******

and it should work fine. Hope that helps